# How to create a global component in Nuxt.js 3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have a nuxt 3 project that has multiple layouts. I'd like to create a global component that runs once when the client first requests my site. And I don't want it to unmount when the user changes layouts. Is this possible with Nuxt 3?

Here is the global component:

```
<template>
  <component is="script" src="https://js.pusher.com/8.0.0/pusher.min.js" />
</template>

<script setup>
onMounted(() => {
  console.log('mounted here')
  var pusher = new Pusher('APP_ID', {
  cluster: 'CLUSTER_ID',
  })

  var channel = pusher.subscribe('notifications-general')

  channel.bind('PATH, function (data) {
    console.log('here in execute')
    alert(data.notification.body_en)
  })
})
</script>
```

Comment: A component instance is, at least in theory, bound to a particular DOM node. It's unmounted when the DOM node is removed by context logic. It sounds like what you really need is a store, which allows persisting data across an application without being bound to any DOM node. That being said, the app itself is a good place to keep anything you want persisted across multiple "pages". And it's never "unmounted".

Comment: If you have to run  only Javascript logic then you can use client middleware

Comment: @tao Thanks. I even forgot that I had app.vue

Comment: @nur_riyad middlewares are ran on every route change i guess. That will not work for me.

Comment: You can use Named route middleware that can be run for only one page or routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting that logic in `src/app.vue`, in theory this should never unmount until the browser it's self is closed?
Perhaps this will work?

```js
<template>

  <component is="script" src="https://js.pusher.com/8.0.0/pusher.min.js" />

  <nuxt-layout>
    <nuxt-page />
  </nuxt-layout>

</template>

<script setup>
onMounted(() => {
  console.log('mounted here')
  var pusher = new Pusher('APP_ID', {
  cluster: 'CLUSTER_ID',
  })

  var channel = pusher.subscribe('notifications-general')

  channel.bind('PATH, function (data) {
    console.log('here in execute')
    alert(data.notification.body_en)
  })
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. TBH I even forgot that I have the app.vue.